# tvOS - Change the width of UICollectionViewCell when focused

Tags: objective-c, swift, tvos

I have a requirement in tvOS to change the width of  UICollectionViewCell when focused (width = 250) and when it unfocused, then reduce the width to normal (width = 150)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution that doesn’t look perfect, but can solve your problem:

```
class SomeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    ...

    private let normalCellWidth:  CGFloat = 150
    private let focusedCellWidth: CGFloat = 250

    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

        let scaleXValue: CGFloat = focusedCellWidth/normalCellWidth
        let scaleFactor = self.isFocused ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleXValue, y: 1.0): CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        self.transform = scaleFactor
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried but UI doesn't look good. I have proposed a new design to the client so hopefully, I don't have to implement this

Comment: Sometimes it’s not so easy :) Good luck!